# Sparse Matrix ValueError: row index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I have a sparse matrix in the form of (inl, outl, 1) that I want to convert into a nxn matrix (value is 1 if there is a link between a and b).

However there are multiple b values for each a, which I believe is why the ValueError message is popping up. I've tried csr, coo, csc, bsr matrixes, to no avail...

M = coo_matrix( (yn, (inl,outl)), shape=(n,n) ).toarray()

ValueError: 'row index exceeds matrix dimensions'

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd check `max(inl)` to see if you have a row index that's bigger than `n`.

Comment: max(inl) equals n...
for csr error message is len(self.indptr),major_dim + 1)) -- ValueError: index pointer size 400000 should be 80000
for coo ValueError 'arr.size x arr.dtype.itemsize' is larger than maximum possible size

Comment: if you've set `n = max(inl)`, your error is because `range(n)` goes from `0` to `n-1`.  That one max data point is out of range.  set `n = max(inl) + 1`

Comment: nope... tried that. i'm still having problems importing and i think it has something to do with the "index pointer size" which i believe is derived from my data (where there are multiple out values for each in) rather than from my settings? sigh.. is there some other library i can use to work with sparse data?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the global max from both the `intl` and `outl` and it works for me. The code is as follows:

```
n = max(max(intl), max(outl)) + 1
```

I hope this would help!